# React Native Getting this.state.input stored as Undefined Work fined in React Native Web

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

React Native Getting this.state.input stored as undefined Works fined in React Native Web

I have been a react dev for a while wanted to build a simple to do app with react native with some networking components got stuck trying to figure out why this.state.input is being stored as an undefined primitive value new to react native i thing my react knowledge might be  my clouding my perspective

Also the https post request with axios works fine but keeps getting stored as undefined

BTW i searched stackoverflow for a solution tried every vague solution i could find so this is unlikely to be a duplicate question

Don't know if it is a lifecycle issue or a binding issue or a react-native api issue cant't seem to figure it out

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {View, Text, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      messages: '',
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.sendMessage = this.sendMessage.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      input: event.target.value,
    });
  }
  sendMessage() {
    const sendIt = `${this.state.input}`;// this.state.input RETRIEVED AND STORED AS UNDEFINED
    const todol = {
      todo: `${sendIt}`,
    };

    console.log(sendIt); // GETTING UNDEFINED HERE WORKS FINE WITH REACT NATIVE WEB

    axios
      .post('http://10.120.1.190:7000/todos/add', todol)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({messages: JSON.stringify(res.data)});
        console.log(this.state.messages);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(`${err}`));
    this.setState({
      input: '',
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.old}>Type in a new Message:</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.old}
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.sendMessage}></Button>
        <Text>{this.state.messages}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
// Change code above this line

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  old: {
    fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 30,
    margin: 'auto',
  },

  new: {
    fontFamily: 'Lato',
    fontSize: 25,
    lineHeight: 30,
    margin: 'auto',
  },
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

We generally use onChangeText to handle text input changes in react-native.

Your TextInput must be like this:

```
<TextInput
    style={styles.old}
    value={this.state.input}
    onChangeText={text =>
      this.setState({
        input: text
      })
    }
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**According to the documentation**

#### onChange

Callback that is called when the text input's text changes.

This will be called with `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }`

You should use : `event.text` but, you can also use `onChangeText` as it will provide the text directly.